# Optimize $group in MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, performance, query-performance

I want to optimize MongoDB query aggregation with $group, the $match part is very fast but when I'm trying group the data by coordinates and push in an array 2 fields, the request is very slow, logic. But it is possible to optimize the $group part ? I'm already using the **allowDiskUse**

Details :

MongoDB version : 4.0.10

RAM : 32GO

Execution time : 25 seconds

Number of documents : 10 826 222

Here the query :

```
[
    {
        "$match": {
            "$or": [
                {
                    "$and": [
                        {
                            "$or": [
                                {
                                    "aliments.fruits": "banana"
                                },
                                {
                                    "parents": {
                                        "$in": [
                                            "banana"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "aliments": {
                        "$in": [
                            "banana"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "coordinates": "$coordinates"
            },
            "File": {
                "$push": {
                    "Id": "$_id",
                    "Paths": "$path"
                }
            }
        }
    }
],{allowDiskUse : true}
```

Data example :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f7ed5907e170000b2005fa5"),
    "path" : "C:\\photos\\test_file_20.docx",
    "text" : "banana is good",
    "type" : "text",
    "page" : 1,
    "aliments" : {
        "fruits" : "banana",
        "vegetable" : "bean"
    },
    "parents" : [ 
        "banana",
        "coco",
        "orange"
    ],
    "coordinates" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            48.8534, 
            2.3488
        ]
    },
    "date" : ISODate("2020-10-08T09:02:08.700Z"),
    "name" : "test_file_20",
}
```

DB stats :

```
{
    "db" : "505cef81-5d89-44f6-80ad-4721e93d9715",
    "collections" : 4,
    "views" : 0,
    "objects" : 14,
    "avgObjSize" : 5568.64285714286,
    "dataSize" : 77961.0,
    "storageSize" : 118784.0,
    "numExtents" : 0,
    "indexes" : 4,
    "indexSize" : 69632.0,
    "fsUsedSize" : 228811964416.0,
    "fsTotalSize" : 254930128896.0,
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data ?

Comment: Sure ! I did it

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this.

It seems a little faster on the dataset I've created. But I've only added 10 000 elements, and I've made some random data so it's not representative of your database.

```
[
    {
        "$match": {
            "$or": [
                {
                    "$or": [
                        {
                            "aliments.fruits": "banana"
                        },
                        {
                            "parents": {
                                "$in": [
                                    "banana"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "aliments": {
                        "$in": [
                            "banana"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$coordinates.coordinates",
            "ids": {
                "$push": "$_id"
            },
            "files": {
                "$push": "$path"
            }
        }
    }
]
```